# Example of Soundness & Completeness of Inference

Tags: logic

Is the following example correct about whether an *inference* algorithm is *sound* and *complete*?

Suppose we have needles a, b, c in a haystack, and have also an inference algorithm that is designed to find needles.

- *sound* - Only needles a, b and c are obtained.
- *complete* - Needles a, b and c are obtained. Other hay may also be obtained.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have almost got it right, but your definition of soundness is not quite right, *or perhaps too subtle.*

I would say that the inference algorithm is sound if *everything returned is a needle* (hence some needles may be missed) and complete if *all needles are returned* (hence some hay may be returned too).

Comment: This may be an issue of language semantics. Assuming the only objects beside hay are the three needles, the OP's phrasing is correct.

Comment: In any case,  my answer spells it out to make it clearer.

Comment: Indeed, if the phrasing were "Only needles a, b and c _can be_ obtained" I wouldn't have given an answer.

Comment: So it seems *sound* means that the algorithmic function has range being needles, and it being *complete* means the function is surjective to the set of needless in the haystack ;-)